# Is it a good idea to use an enum parameter in public API function in C?

Tags: c, api, enums, api-design

I am designing a C API which among other things has to provide a way to set some double-valued options. To identify the options I use the following enum:

```
typedef enum
{
    OptionA,
    OptionB,
    ...
} Option;
```

Is it a good idea to use `Option` as a parameter type in a public API function:

```
int set_option(Option opt, double value);
```

or is it better to use `int` instead:

```
int set_option(int opt, double value);
```

considering that I may need to add more options in the future?

Also are there any good examples of existing APIs that demonstrate either approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using an `enum` you are effectively helping the user of your function to know what valid values are available.
Of course the drawback is that whenever a new option is added you will need to modify the header and thus the user may need to recompile his code whereas if it is an `int` he may not have to do that.

Comment: Requiring the user to recompile his code worries me most. Is there a way to avoid it when adding new options in the first approach (with enum as a parameter)?

Comment: Why would adding new options for a re-compile? Old code would still work. If you want access to the new feature then it's not unreasonable to ask for a re-compile. And if you used and int instead then you'd define it as a constant in your header file so there'd be a recompile there too.

Comment: One might raise the rather obvious point that in order to *use* the new value, one has to change and recompile that code anyway.  Adding a new enum value would not require any existing code to be recompiled.

Answer (score 1):

Enums give you the advantage of compile time checking that the value is sane.  Then you would have to add the new options to a new version of your header file if you add options in the future.

Comment: How so? C seems to happily accept any integer when calling a function that expects an enum parameter. (At least with whatever warnings that are enabled by default in an XCode project.)

Comment: You must be thinking of some other langugage. C enums are just integers. No real type safety at all.

Comment: I have definitely seen compilers generate warnings when passing ints as enums when the int doesn't fall in the enum declared range.  Maybe it's just an optional nice thing for compilers to warn about?