# Use enum as type can be consider a good practice in C?

Tags: c, enums

Consider the following example:

```
enum my_enum
{
    ENUMERATER_1,
    ENUMERATER_2,
    ENUMERATER_TOTAL,
}
typedef enum my_enum my_enum_t                 // just if using option 2

static int use_my_enum(int myenum);            // 1
static int use_my_enum(my_enum_t myenum);      // 2
static int use_my_enum(enum my_enum myenum);   // 3
```

What option may be consider the best practice, 1, 2 or 3?

In advance, my opinion is that you should always use type `int`, as `enums` are `int` by the standard, you can assign any value to a `enum` type, and if you use any of the other options, you may have the illusion that you do not need to test if your argument is valid or not. Using `int` as the type of the `enum` argument, its more clear that you should always confirm the input argument.

I found may reason to use the `enum` as a type for all others program languages, but not for C, there is any reason for considering options 2 or 3 a better practice than 1?

Conclusion:
As there was no technical issue, it is not wrong to afirm that is just a personal preference. Anyway, I will reconsider my first assumption and take the option #3 as a slightly better practice because of readability.

Comment: I would say the last since it's clearer and more strict. Option 2 is okay if you want to drive people crazy with finding the definition.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119359/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-an-enum-parameter-in-public-api-function-in-c?rq=1

Comment: Option #2 for me. It is more concise and avoids the verbose enum keyword in the parameter. Now a days, developers have good IDEs to easily find the underlying types.

Comment: I would define the type and enum in one typedef and not have the named enum at all.  As in `typedef enum { ... } my_enum;` (IIRC; it's been a long while since I coded C every day).

Comment: I'd say #3, since it's the most straight forward. It requires no guessing at all (#2 is also popular though I guess).

Comment: see [Grouping Related Objective-C Constants](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/objective-c_and_c_code_customization/grouping_related_objective-c_constants) for use of Apple's typedefs, especially useful for bridging to Swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with using any of them.

With modern IDEs, if it's a good one, the second one is what I would prefer.

The first is fine as well but you may find people "faking it" and not using the actual values. For example, throw a 4 in as a parameter and it might lead to undesired behavior.

It comes down to personal preference. You'll probably find most prefer #2.

Comment: Definitely (2).  Not (3), because if you're going to define a type, then define one and use it, darn it.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey agreed, it was just an example, but a good point, I will edit the question make it more clear.

Comment: And what is that good modern IDE for C development you're talking about?!

Comment: Ha! So true! Time to do what C++ programmers did with C: Piggyback another language ;)

Answer (score 6):

I would do:

```
typedef enum
{
    ENUMERATER_1,
    ENUMERATER_2,
    ENUMERATER_TOTAL,
} my_enum;
```

Also, type names ending with `_t` are reserved for next POSIX standards.

Comment: +1 for : `type names ending with _t are reserved for next POSIX standards.`